FTP Server responds on localhost, but not pc on same subnet
I am now running Ubuntu 22.04 after recently upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04.  I am using the latest vsftpd.  I have verified that I can ftp to the localhost and see the contents of the directory once I'm connected.
I have also run a systemctl status and vsftpd is running.
I am running ufw and status from that shows I am accepting ftp connections.
21/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
20/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
When I attempt an ftp connection from another pc on the same subnet, I get a connection timeout.
I'm also running a webserver on this machine and I can get to that from other machines on the network.

Since Ubuntu 18.04LTS (Bionic Beaver) became unsupported in April, 2023, Ubuntu 18.04  has passed its End-Of-Life date, and is no longer supported on AskUbuntu.  Please install to a supported release. See https://www.releases.ubuntu.com/ Your task would be made easier if /home were a seperate partition.

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reached End of Standard Support last year, and is thus off-topic on this site.  You can use ESM/Pro support options (cost maybe involved) if you wish but community support (such as this site) no longer exists, though SE Unix & Linux allow all Ubuntu questions too.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic or Canonical who provide ESM/Pro services.

I have upgraded to 22.04 and still have the same issue.

@PaulWilliamson, You should have updated your question.
